# Clear Fragment content when back button pressed

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, fragment

I want my fragment to be cleared when I pressed back button.

**Desired cycle**:
When I click **item1** in my Activity's Listview, I want it to show only **item1** content on my Fragment. When I pressed back and click on **item2**, I want only **item2** there. But at the moment, both **item1** and **item2** are in my fragment.

This is how I initiate my fragment:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fixtures);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            mFixtureInfo = new FixtureInfoFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.containerMain, mFixtureInfo)
                    .commit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: proivde your xml code for fragment.

Comment: It seems the easiest way is to have two fragments for item1 and item2 content separately, and then just use regular FragmentManager to switch your two fragments in your "container"

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing this post with any new information you had, any new code you'd tried, or an explanation of why any posted answers weren't working would've bumped it to the top of the active queue. I've closed this as a duplicate of the newer one, since you're currently getting answers there, but, in the future, please just edit the original.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new here. I'll make sure I won't do it again

Answer (score 0):

Try to call new instance of fragment whenever you want your fragment to be open.

It will create a fresh fragment every time.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fixtures);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
      FixtureInfoFragment   mFixtureInfo = new FixtureInfoFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.containerMain, mFixtureInfo)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

Not globally declare you  FixtureInfoFragmet.

Comment: I tried this and the problem still there. 
When I click item1 in my Listview, I want it to show only item1 content on the Fragment. When I pressed back and click on item2, I want only item2 there.

But at the moment, both item1 and item2 are in my fragment.

Answer (score 0):

You should clear backstack of the fragments in the activity instantSatate holder

`@override
onBackPressed(){
    clearBackTrace(intent);
}`

Comment: what's clearBackTrace ???